# Dataframe can't fill NaN values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with some NaN values, that I want to fit with the mean of my DataFrame

```
data.fillna(data.mean())
```

afterwards, I check to see if there are any NaN or null values left

```
 print('is nan', data.isna().values.any()) #prints True
 print('is null', data.isnull().values.any()) #prints True
```

before prints to be true, and I don't understand since the NaN values should be filled.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to change your dataframe in place:

```
data.fillna(data.mean(), inplace=True)
```

Or do this to create a new dataframe with NaNs replaced by `data.mean()`:

```
data_new = data.fillna(data.mean())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
# generate sample dataframe some filled with NaN
data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [np.nan, 4], [5, 6], [7, np.nan]], columns=["A", "B"])
# apply per-column and substitue the mean of that columns 
data.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=1)
```